# Lightweight smbclient analog for embedded device

Tags: c++, linux, qt, embedded

On our embedded devices we use nbtscan and smbclient utilities to find shared folders in local network. For our new device we have strong restriction on size of the rootfs. We had to sacrifice the smbclient and related libraries to free up disk space for other functionality. Are there any other way to support folder sharing on device? Below are utilites and tools I have on my device:
**nbtscan**
**qt5**
**busybox**
**mount**
To support this functionality I have 5 Mbytes of flash memory.

Answer (score 0):

Not think that you can found solution smaller or simpler than smbclient. 
You can try recompile smbclient to optimize size and exclude extra info. But think true way is change protocol to ftp or http and use another small client. May be curl.

UPD: Please check samba-commander project . I not sure with that. But may help